# What is the dependence of size of Nd:YAG crystal for making Nd:YAG lasers?

Tags: laser

Assume that we are able to grow a 1 meter long and 5 cm thick Nd:YAG crystal using best possible growth facility. Is it possible to generate a high power Nd:YAG laser using this big crystal?

Comment: Not enough information. Who said we don't grow such big crystals? What is high power to you? Because the answer is "Yes we can" to both those questions, and also "the limit is this for this and this assumptions", meaning that then the answer becomes "no, we can't have high power laser". And although I have enough knowledge to answer those questions, I am not inclined to do lengthy calculations for a general case, with such low amount of information. i.e. your question is too broad and you should specify what you need.

Comment: Fiber lasers are a lot longer than a meter. Just saying...